# Loopback unauthorized request when trying to login

Tags: express, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have created a custom user model that inherits form the built-in User model. Then I added a boot script that creates a default user.

```
 User.create([{
   username: 'admin',
   email: 'email@email.com',
   password: 'admin'
}], on_usersCreated);
```

This creates a document in the monogdb database,. However when I try to login, it send a 401 unauthorized request.

I tried to find the root of the problem, and it seems that loopback cannot fins such user in the database. More specifically, in node_modules/loopback/common/models/user there is this:

```
self.findOne({where: query}, function(err, user) {
  var defaultError = new Error('login failed');
  defaultError.statusCode = 401;
  ....
```

where

```
query = { email: "email@email.com" }
```

But the problem is that it cannot find a user with that email in the database although it does exist.

This is the user.json file

```
{
  "name": "user",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [
   {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
   },
   {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "admin",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
   }
 ],
 "methods": []
}
```

Comment: When you call `User.create`, did you assign `User` like `var User = app.models.User` or `var User = app.models.user`.

Comment: User = app.models.User

Comment: It should be `var user = app.models.user` because you are extending the built-in `User`.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this issue. As  @superkhau stressed out, you should use the custom User model to create the default users.

Additionally, I had to expose the user model API and hide the build-in User API; So in model-config.js

```
 ...
 "User": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
 },

 "user": {
   "dataSource": "db",
   "public": true
 },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have two collections: User and user. In your models, user extends from User. Which model did you use the create the user record?

Comment: It appears to be the uppercase user:

    User.create([{
      username: 'admin',
      ...

Comment: I'm using User = app.models.User and on the front-end 
User.login({ rememberMe: true }, {email: $scope.user.email, password: $scope.user.password})

Comment: I manually renamed the user collection to User and it worked. Why does it create a user collection in the first place, why not call it User? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Because you are extending the built-in `User` model with your own model `user`. `user.json` shows `..."base": "User",...` in your code above.